Largest chain in poset
I want to know whether for all infinite cardinals $\alpha$, a chain in $(P(\alpha),\subseteq)$ with cardinality greater than $\alpha$ necessarily exists in ZFC. For $\alpha=\aleph_0$, I know using Dedekind cuts, a chain of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ exists. This answer shows a chain of size $\aleph_2$ exists when $\alpha=\aleph_1$. But I don't know if the same is true for larger cardinalities.

Assuming GCH, then the same proof as the CH case of the linked answer shows the answer is yes.

in James E. Baumgartner's paper Almost-disjoint sets, the dense set problem and the partition calculus, Ann. Math. Logic. 10 (1976) 401–439, he defines a property $D(\kappa,\lambda)$ which is equivalent (Theorem 2.1(b)) to the assertion that $P(\kappa)$ contains a chain of cardinality $\lambda$. As I haven't read the paper, I don't know if it answers your question. Of course the paper is almost 50 years old, so the results may have been improved.
